# HQL passing parameter using HashMap with leading space

Tags: java, hql

I am trying to pass a parameter using HashMap but when my parameter has leading space, I get no results even if there is a record in the database. However, any other username without leading space is ok.

```
String hql = "FROM Tbusermember WHERE username = :user";
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("user", " 1231");
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setProperties(params);
```

Comment: Do u have leading spaces in matching rows of DB?

Comment: @PramodNikam yes